# How to make android application recognize MMS messages only from one mobile number?

Tags: android, xml, sms, mms

I'm working on android application which should receive MMS\SMS message from a unique
number, but I don't know how can I write a code that make this application receive 
these messages from only this number.

Can anyone help?

Note :
This unique number for our server just for making tests.